# Keyup permitir que contenha apenas um ponto entre os caracteres digitados em input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal como permitir que contenha apenas um ponto (.) entre os caracteres digitados no input fazendo a checagem com o evento keyup do jquery.

Exemplo de saida:

```
000.000000
1.000
99.9.99.999 // <- error não pode ter mais de 1 ponto
```

Code:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
  $(this).val(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    return val.replace(/(\.)+/g, function(char, str) {
      return str;
    });
  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4acbc715/1/)

Comment: Lembre-se de ajustar a posição do cursor quando filtrar este tipo de entrada que muda o tamanho da string, senão fica horrível de usar o input.

Answer (score 2):

Criei uma funcao chamado `validaPontos()` que  retornara a quantidade de pontos que estiverem no campo. apos isto e so comparar se e maior ou igual a dois e se for remover o caracter.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
  var valor = this.value;
  var pattern = /\.(?=[^.]*$)/;
  if (validaPontos(valor) >= 2) {
    this.value = valor.replace(pattern, "");
  }
});

function validaPontos(valor) {
  var quantidadeDePontos = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {
    if (valor[i] === '.') {
      quantidadeDePontos++;
    }
  }
  return quantidadeDePontos;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

**Atualizado** Se o usuário tentar digitar um ponto no meio será removido o ultimo ponto da string!

Ou você pode também usar um plugin para essas validações: [MaskMoney](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/)

**Exemplo de Uso:**

```js
$('#currency').maskMoney();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="currency" />
```

Comment: Nessa caso, se eu colocar um ponto ao meio aos outros caracteres, o ponto fica e sai o último caractere.

Comment: @SamirBraga é verdade! é mais chato do que me parecia kkkk.

Comment: @SamirBraga da uma olhada.

Answer (score 1):

Bem... isso me deu um certo trabalho, mas acho que finalmente consegui algo bastante interessante. Olhe:

Com a existência de um ponto, caso você tente acrescentar outro depois deste você não conseguirá, para isso o ponto deverá ser apagado. Ao invés do `onKey`, utilizei o `onInput`, que detectará se algo é mudado, com isso o usuário pode "navegar" entra as lestras sem ser jogado para o final da `input`, além da questão do desempenho, pois nesse caso é imperceptível a exclusão do ponto.

```js
$('input').on("input", function(){
  var val = this.value;
  var test = /^[^.]?.[^.]*$/;
  if(test.test(val)){
    return;
  }else{
    var n = val.search(/\./);
    var beforeDot = val.substring(0, n);
    var dot = val.substring(n, n+1);
    var afterDot = val.substring(n+1, val.length);
    $(this).val(beforeDot.replace(/\./g, "") + dot + afterDot.replace(/\./g, ""));
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: segue esta logica mesmo, porem se o usuario apagar o primeiro ponto usado ele nao podera digitar novamente

Comment: Esse é realmente um problema sério.. tentarei solucioná-lo e editarei a resposta...

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, dê uma olhada nessa edição.

Comment: +1, esta igual a minha, eu identifiquei um problema nas nossas, voce sabe dizer qual e ?

Comment: Do que se trata esse problema que você identificou? Não entendi. Ainda persiste um problema?

Comment: O problema e nao permitir mais que 1 ponto certo? depois que digitou o primeiro ponto ele não deve ser modificado. nossos algoritmos removem o ultimo ponto, quer dizer que, se voce tiver 123.456 e adicionar um ponto no 1 ficara 1.23456 e desta forma excluira o primeiro ponto que deveria estar por padrão

Comment: Entendo. É realmente algo chato. Posso tentar ajustar isso, mas veremos o que o autor acha, primeiramente. :)

Comment: Sem duvidas,  como eu disse na minha resposta, se for levar essa validação para todo um sistema e aconselhado usar um plugin de mascara para facilitar.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui um modo mais "compacto" semelhante ao do @GabrielRodrigues

```js
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
  $(this).val(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if (val.split('.').length > 2) val = val.replace(/\.+$/, '');
    return val;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Smigol, O problema é quando o usuario tenta inserir pontos no meio do input, se ele fizer isto dará erro no seu código.